# How can I get a different transition animation for insertion & removal?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can specify a different transition for when the view is inserted vs removed:

```swift
.transition(
    .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: .leading)
        removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
    )
)
```

This works fine. However I would like it so ease in quickly, when it is added, and ease out slowly when removed. The following does not appear to do anything, despite compiling just fine.

```swift
.transition(
    .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: .leading)
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 2)),
        removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 5))
    )
)
```

Am I misunderstanding the use of `.animation` as a modifier on transitions?

Demo code:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var showDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press to show details") {
                withAnimation {
                    showDetails.toggle()
                }
            }

            if showDetails {
                Text("Details go here.")
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .transition(
                        .asymmetric(
                            insertion: .move(edge: .leading)
                                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 5)),
                            removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
                                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 5))
                        )
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that I found to work.  Use a different `withAnimation` call with each direction:

```
Button("Press to show details") {
    if !showDetails {
        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2)) {
            showDetails.toggle()
        }
    } else {
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 5)) {
            showDetails.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit animation can be provided right in `withAnimation` call, so here is a solution.

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
Button("Press to show details") {
    withAnimation(!showDetails ? .easeIn(duration: 2) : .easeOut(duration: 5)) {
        showDetails.toggle()
    }
}

if showDetails {
    Text("Details go here.")
        .background(Color.blue)
        .transition(
            .asymmetric(
                insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
            )
        )
}
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTransitionDifferentAnimations.swift)